# RegEx for matching a special alphanumeric pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Hello Im new at regex so;
I want to get only 8 digit char from a complicated code here;

```
["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","AAA","SSS","sDDD","mFFFa"],"gaa":"aaa","timasa});
    **var csrf_token = '551a8513';**

    Unimportanttext = '/justanothernonimportanttext&&h=551a8513';
```

I tried `token\s=\s'[^']*` but it resuts : `["token = '551a8513"]`
I just need `551a8513` this part. Can you help me with regex code. Thanks
Low english level so may be I have mistakes. Im sorry

EDIT : 
We got 2 answers in here and both of them works!
1)

```
token = re.findall("(?<=csrf_token = ')[^\']+",driver.page_source)
print(link + str(token[0]))
```

2)

```
token = re.findall("csrf_token = '(.+)'", driver.page_source)
print(link + str(token[0]))
```

Thank you both of you! I hope you live well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our desired output has numbers followed by lowercase letters and numbers. We can capture that using an expression similar to:

```
([0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEEBzl/1)

Or we can capture it using:

```
(([a-z]+)?([0-9]+))
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9P0uHl/1)

Or we can simply use the `'` before and after:

```
'(.+)'
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6uYDc/1)

We can also add more boundaries. Such as:

```
csrf_token = '(.+)'
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a40P8S/1)

Based on [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)'s advice, it is much safe and better to modify it as:

```
csrf_token = '(.+?)'
```

#### Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = """

["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","AAA","SSS","sDDD","mFFFa"],"gaa":"aaa","timasa});
    **var csrf_token = '551a8513';**

    Unimportanttext = '/justanothernonimportanttext&&h=551a8513';

"""
expression = r'csrf_token = \'(.+?)\''
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "551a8513" is a match
```

Comment: If I can make a suggestion you could make the quantifier non greedy in case there are more `'` following `csrf_token = '(.+?)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this positive lookbehind pattern:

```
(?<=csrf_token = ')[^\']+
```

This will return whatever is wrapped in single quotes ('value') after "csrf_token = ". Basically, it will match what you were getting but only return the part of the string you care about. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, firstly thanks for your help I really stuck in here. Your code has worked but It takes output like :['551a8513']   Is there any way to delete those ['   and '] too?

Comment: @HasanOnurATAÇ This pattern should not match the single quotes, only what is inside the single quotes. Can you edit your question with an updated code snippet? Maybe something else is going on.

Comment: I think you don't have to escape the quote in the character class and the pattern does not guarantee a closing `'` I think you could use a positive lookahead `(?<=csrf_token = ')[^']+(?=')`